# After resizing an event existing events get faded. - React Big calendar

Tags: reactjs, events, calendar, resize, react-big-calendar

**Before resizing an event.**

[image]

**After resizing an event.**

[image]

Why does this happen? Anyone's there to help please, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved !!!**

The issue was with the **'key'** used inside the React big calendar component. Remove that '**key**' and try it may work for you as well.